# Bootstrap - Test jquery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying the bootstrap framework, specifically that jquery shows modal screen but it doesn't works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>AddCloud - Edicions</title>
</head>

<body>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="table_search" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>CCA</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>  
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>b</td>
                        <td>c</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <script>
            $('#table_search > tbody').on('click', '>tr', function () {
                 alert( $(this).text());
            });


            $('#table_search > tbody > tr').dblclick(function () {
                alert($(this).text());
            });
        </script>

        <script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code is very easy, I don't understand why it doesn't work :(

Is it possible the problem is the file contain the jquery or I don't know.

Regards,

Comment: what does the console say? and where do you include bootstrap?

Comment: Please have a look at [these](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) examples. You are missing more then half of the necessary code for the modals to work. Including bootstrap itself and the html container.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'm going to see the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In your header - you haven't actually added bootstrap into your document.

Also move

```
<script src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To your header above all of these three links. This should be loaded first to be used in Bootstrap.

If you copy all of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<title>AddCloud - Edicions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      Launch demo modal
    </button>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="table_search" class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CCA</td>
                            <td>Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>  
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>a</td>
                            <td>b</td>
                            <td>c</td>
                        </tr>


      </tbody>
            </table>
       </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#table_search > tbody').on('click', '>tr', function () {
         alert( $(this).text());
    });


    $('#table_search > tbody > tr').dblclick(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
</script>
```

Into your `.html` file, it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Already I see the problem, the includes!